# Printed Report is not recognizing margins

Tags: crystal-reports, printing

I have an application developed in vb using .net framework.  We are using Crystal Reports XI runtime to run reports from this application.  When I view the reports in Crystal, they are properly centered on the page, however, when we view the report on screen it all looks correct, however, when we send it to the printer, the report is high on the page and to the left margin.  Can anyone give me a work around for this?  We generally print the reports to screen first and then to Adobe PDF.

Thanks for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Go to File/Page Setup and make sure your margins are set up correctly. This also could be a printer driver issue.